# Subdomain (host) based routing in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, subdomain

I've been Googling for some time, but can't find any useful answers.  I'm trying to get a subdomain for an api on my website `api.example.com`. However, all answers said that I needed to change my DNS to redirect `api.example.com` to `example.com/api`, which I don't want. Is it possible to just serve `api.` instead of redirect to `/api`? How would I go about doing that?

1. I'm using express.
2. I don't want to use any other packages that aren't built-in.

```js
const path = require('path'),
      http = require('http'),
      https = require('https'),
      helmet = require('helmet'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express();

const mainRouter = require('./routers/mainRouter.js');

// security improvements
app.use(helmet());

// main pages
app.use('/', mainRouter);

// route the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(/* API subdomain router... */)

// 404s
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views/404.html"));
})
```

Comment: how You use Your app? nginx -> proxy_pass http://yourapp  ?

Comment: Just a regular node server, no other services

Comment: Set up another virtual host entry in your front-end server, or have Express pay attention to the `Host` header sent in.

Comment: what's inside app.js (or Your app start file) ?

Comment: @num8er Edited it in

Comment: Is your API and Website code in the same directory/project, where you serve them both?

Comment: Just a small point, you say you don't want to use any modules that aren't "built in", but you're already using express and helmet, neither of which are built in.  What's the problem with using something like [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-vhost)?

Comment: Usually modules aren't needed. Thus I try limiting them.

Comment: @lieuwe_berg I don't like to use too much packages from external sources due their immatureness. So I've written in my answer how to forward request to some external app/router.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend You to use nginx and separate api service.

But because of some reasons You cannot avoid it (or You don't want it, cause You just want show prototype to customer ASAP).

You can write middleware that will catch host from header and forward to some custom router:

1) `/middlewares/forwardForSubdomain.js`:

```
module.exports = 
    (subdomainHosts, customRouter) => {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        let host = req.headers.host ? req.headers.host : ''; // requested hostname is provided in headers
        host = host.split(':')[0]; // removing port part

        // checks if requested host exist in array of custom hostnames
        const isSubdomain = (host && subdomainHosts.includes(host));
        if (isSubdomain) { // yes, requested host exists in provided host list
          // call router and return to avoid calling next below
          // yes, router is middleware and can be called
          return customRouter(req, res, next); 
        }

        // default behavior
        next();
      }
    };
```

2) api router as an example `/routers/apiRouter.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  // some operations here
});

module.exports = router;
```

3) attach middleware before `/` handler:

```
const path = require('path'),
      http = require('http'),
      https = require('https'),
      helmet = require('helmet'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express();

const mainRouter = require('./routers/mainRouter');

// security improvements
app.use(helmet());

// ATTACH BEFORE ROUTING
const forwardForSubdomain = require('./middlewares/forwardForSubdomain');
const apiRouter = require('./routers/apiRouter');
app.use(
  forwardForSubdomain(
    [
      'api.example.com',
      'api.something.com'
    ],
    apiRouter
  )
);

// main pages
app.use('/', mainRouter);

// route the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// 404s
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views/404.html"));
})
```

P.S. It does the same that in [express-vhost](https://github.com/doanythingfordethklok/express-vhost) package, [look at the code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doanythingfordethklok/express-vhost/master/lib/vhost.js)

Comment: Not sure why someone gave you the -1, this is a solid answer.  Though perhaps it'd be improved if you commented your custom router code a bit to explain what it's doing for a new person viewing. Also you are importing the express router, but not using it, so that seems odd.

Comment: @Paul I was writing and saving... Seems like someone don't like to read "progressive answers" (:

Comment: Thanks, this worked. (Although copying the code from here AND the package didn't, so I just installed the package myself. Not an issue with the code, but with some express error surrounding app.use.)

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be possible to point just the subdomain (api.example.com) to your api server.

DNS doesn't control subdirectories so a DNS entry of `example.com/api` would be invalid

If you have an IP address for your server you will need to add an A record with the value: `api.example.com`.

If you have a domain name for your server you will need to create a CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official vhost plugin for Express.js: https://github.com/expressjs/vhost

What you are describing, having multiple domains/hostnames hosted/handled by a single server, is typically referred to as a "vhost" (virtual host).